# Where is classes.dex in the apk?

Tags: java, android

I have questions about android apk file. I could find classes.dex in apk file before, but I can not find classes.dex in apk file now. 
If I can not find classes.dex in apk file, where can I find the classes.dex?
 Can the apk start without classes.dex? 
Thank you.

Comment: it is there only where it used to be just rename .apk to .jar and extract you will find it

Comment: I already try to chage .apk to .jar. but i could not find classes.dex.

Comment: then it is possible u have a faulty try rebuilding the .apk and see

Comment: run this: `unzip -l your_app.apk | grep classes.dex`

Comment: Thank you. I tried "unzip -l your_app.apk | grep classes.dex", but no classes.dex.

Comment: so remove `| grep classes.dex` and see the output

Comment: I tried "unzip -l your_app.apk", but i could not see classes.dex.

Comment: so what is inside?

Comment: res folder(drawable,layout,raw,xml) and res file, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, CERT.SF, CERT.RSA, AndroidManifest.xml, assets folder and xml files, etc

Comment: and you are sure you built that apk with no failures?

Comment: i think that our engineer may use to enable pre-optimization option. i will check our engineer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple: you are in front of an odex apk.

Odex apk lacks of classes.dex and during installation they will generate an .odex file.

This .odex file is an optimized version of the classes.dex.